# format the timestamp using the find command

Tags: linux, date, find, printf

this command uses `-printf '%Tc %p\n'` to give the date the files where last modified.

```
$ find ./ -daystart -mtime -3 -type f  ! -mtime -1  -printf '%Tc %p\n'
Tue 08 Mar 2016 12:25:01 NZDT ./compareKPIs-log
Tue 08 Mar 2016 18:04:58 NZDT ./backup_public_html_20160308.tgz
Tue 08 Mar 2016 18:04:58 NZDT ./log-file
Tue 08 Mar 2016 12:25:01 NZDT ./compareKPIs-error
Mon 07 Mar 2016 18:05:02 NZDT ./backup_public_html_20160307.tgz
```

what I want to do is control the date format to be `YYYY-mm-dd`. How do I do this? (hh:mm:ss can be added here also if necessary)

for instance `-printf '%TY %p\n'` will give me the year`%TY`:

```
$ find ./ -daystart -mtime -3 -type f  ! -mtime -1  -printf '%TY %p\n'
2016 ./compareKPIs-log
2016 ./backup_public_html_20160308.tgz
2016 ./log-file
2016 ./compareKPIs-error
2016 ./backup_public_html_20160307.tgz
```

for instance `-printf '%Tm %p\n'` will give me the month`%Tm`:

```
$ find ./ -daystart -mtime -3 -type f  ! -mtime -1  -printf '%Tm %p\n'
03 ./compareKPIs-log
03 ./backup_public_html_20160308.tgz
03 ./log-file
03 ./compareKPIs-error
03 ./backup_public_html_20160307.tgz
```

Another [optio](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/using-find-to-print-the-timestamp-810472/)n is to `ls` `-exec ls -ld {} \;` but I am not sure if it is possible this way.

```
$ find ./ -daystart -mtime -3 -type f  ! -mtime -1 -exec ls -ld {} \;
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevinsmith kevinsmith 254160 Mar  8 12:25 ./compareKPIs-log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevinsmith kevinsmith 956411793 Mar  8 18:04 ./backup_public_html_20160308.tgz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevinsmith kevinsmith 78577523 Mar  8 18:04 ./log-file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevinsmith kevinsmith 46080 Mar  8 12:25 ./compareKPIs-error
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevinsmith kevinsmith 956407500 Mar  7 18:05 ./backup_public_html_20160307.tgz
```

Comment: See similar question for more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893022/how-to-display-modified-date-time-with-find-command

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use more than one **%T**k in `-printf` argument of `find`, eg:

- `'%TY-%Tm-%Td %p\n'` for *YYYY-mm-dd [file]* format
- `'%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS %p\n'` for *YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss [file]* format
- `'%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %p\n'` for *YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ssssssssss [file]* format

Comment: Nice tip about the `%.2TS` to truncate the decimals on the seconds!

Comment: To see more documentation: `man find | less -p "Time fields"`